# forcing responsive image to resize instead of paragraph on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Sure this is an easy one but cannot get it working.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2X6pJ/

```
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250"/>
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h3 class="media-heading">Hello</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just want the paragraph of text (well div.media-body) to always be at least 50% of screen width so on smaller screens, the image would get smaller. Adding a min-width just seems to force text below image.

I am using twitter bootstrap so the responsive image stuff is already set up. The problem is that it does not come into effect until the image is the only thing left and all the text has moved beneath (when I resize panel).

Comment: Like this? I changed to position of the image http://jsfiddle.net/2X6pJ/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize the image when the div is resized, try this:

`img { display: block; max-width: 100%; }`

Here a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/2X6pJ/8/

Comment: You'll probably want `height:auto; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic` as well

Comment: thx. the jsfiddle works well on smaller screens, but you widen the panel, the gap between image a text increases rather than having more space for the text itself. Changing your pull-left: width: 50% to max-width seems to fix it. Any issues with doing this?